# Is there a context where the expression `a.b::c` makes sense?

Tags: c++

In C++ consider the grammar rule:

`member-access-expression`: `LHS` `member-access-operator` `RHS`
(op is `.`)
and
`LHS`=unqualified `id-expression` e.g. that references an instance variable.
`RHS`=qualified `id-expression` (with at least one nested identifier)

example: `a.b::c`

If that can ever pass the semantic check, what situation would it be ?

The following experiment:

```
struct B{};

struct A
{
    B b;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.b::c;
}
```

returns

```
'b' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
a.b::c;
  ^
```

([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ke7HXP))

This tends to hint to me that there can't be any legal case of a qualified-id on the right of a member access.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A very simple example is if you want to call a member function of a parent class:

```
struct A {
    void f();
};

struct B: A {
    void f();
};

B b;
b.A::f();
```

Comment: very interesting. then the "kind" referred-to by anything placed in the position of `A` has to be struct/class /union/namespace/enum ?

Comment: @v.oddou   It's not that surprising.    Those "kinds" are what the scope resolution operator is used for.

Comment: @Peter perfect. So I have everything: the grammar is valid; and the semantic situation where it's correct: when `A` refers to a symbol of kind `user defined type`.

Comment: With `A` looked up relatively from the scope of `decltype(b)` ? is it also legal to do `b.::A::f()` ? (seems to build fine in gcc)

Comment: Yes, it is legal.

Comment: furthermore, note that interestingly, the bases are `used` in their children. which pulls their accessibility from the scope of `b` even when in different namespaces: https://godbolt.org/z/fO3pJ1

Comment: You don't even need inheritance. `A::f()` is a valid name for the function `f()` inside `A`, period. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67d13365926585bd

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's true, but I don't see why you would do `a.A::f()` instead of `a.f()`, while I have already used things like `b.A::f()`.

Comment: @Holt You probably wouldn't but it's still valid/legal/"makes sense" and is simpler ;)

Answer (score 10):

One use case is accessing members of an `enum` within some `struct A` by using an instance of `A` (rather than using the enum directly via `A::b::c`):

```
struct A {
    enum class b { c }; // can be unscoped as well
};

A a;
a.b::c; // Access to enum value c - similarly, A::b::c would work
```

Comment: mesmerizing. I knew you could use an instance to access a static field, but not a type. Your answer is important for me to widen the exhaustivity of the use cases of id-expression in combination with member-access-expression. thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Here's a trivial example:

```
struct A {
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.A::f();
}
```

`A::f()` is a *qualified* version of the name for the function `f` that's a member of `A`. You can use it in member access just like the "short" (or *unqualified*) name.

In fact, one might argue that every time you write `a.f()`, that's a *shortcut* for `a.A::f()` (with the `A::` part being taken automatically from `decltype(a)`).

There's nothing magic about this, though it's unusual to see the construct outside of the sort of scenarios the other answerers demonstrated, because in this example it's redundant.

Comment: superb. This is a 3rd example of different flavor which brings value. It confirms that the RHS of a member-access is looked up from the scope of its LHS but the result of the evaluation of the LHS sub-expression is not necessarily used.

Comment: `fully-qualified` is it ? if it lacks the global scope it is qualified but not fully, IMHO.

Comment: @v.oddou Hmm... good question! I don't know actually. It's not a standard term anyway and I can't remember what conventional usage is. I'll just rip out the "fully-" as it's a distraction anyway.